# UIViewRepresentable not show in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit

I have some view for zoomable images

```
struct ViewerFrameView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: ViewerFrameViewModel
    @State var image: UIImage = UIImage()
    
    init(viewModel: ViewerFrameViewModel) {
        self._viewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: viewModel)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if viewModel.downloading {
                LoaderView()
            } else {
                ZoomableScrollView(image: $image)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            DispatchQueue.global().async {
                viewModel.getContent()
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: viewModel.image, perform: { newValue in
            image = newValue
            print(newValue.size)
        })
    }
}
```

ZoomableScrollView is a UIViewRepresentable view that implement inside UIKit UIScrollView:

```
struct ZoomableScrollView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var image: UIImage
    var scrollView = ImageScrollView()
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ImageScrollView {
        return scrollView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ImageScrollView, context: Context) {
        scrollView.set(image: image)
    }
}

class ImageScrollView: UIScrollView, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    
    var imageZoomView: UIImageView!
    
    lazy var zoomingTap: UITapGestureRecognizer = {
        let zoomingTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleZoomingTap))
        zoomingTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
        return zoomingTap
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        self.delegate = self
        self.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        self.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        self.decelerationRate = UIScrollView.DecelerationRate.fast
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func set(image: UIImage) {
        
        imageZoomView?.removeFromSuperview()
        imageZoomView = nil
        imageZoomView = UIImageView(image: image)
        self.addSubview(imageZoomView)
        
        configurateFor(imageSize: image.size)
    }
    
    func configurateFor(imageSize: CGSize) {
        self.contentSize = imageSize
        
        setCurrentMaxandMinZoomScale()
        self.zoomScale = self.minimumZoomScale
        
        self.imageZoomView.addGestureRecognizer(self.zoomingTap)
        self.imageZoomView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        self.centerImage()
    }
    
    func setCurrentMaxandMinZoomScale() {
        let boundsSize = self.bounds.size
        let imageSize = imageZoomView.bounds.size
        
        let xScale = boundsSize.width / imageSize.width
        let yScale = boundsSize.height / imageSize.height
        let minScale = min(xScale, yScale)
        
        var maxScale: CGFloat = 1.0
        if minScale < 0.1 {
            maxScale = 0.3
        }
        if minScale >= 0.1 && minScale < 0.5 {
            maxScale = 0.7
        }
        if minScale >= 0.5 {
            maxScale = max(1.0, minScale)
        }
        
        self.minimumZoomScale = minScale
        self.maximumZoomScale = maxScale
    }
    
    func centerImage() {
        let boundsSize = self.bounds.size
        var frameToCenter = imageZoomView.frame
        
        if frameToCenter.size.width < boundsSize.width {
            frameToCenter.origin.x = (boundsSize.width - frameToCenter.size.width) / 2
        } else {
            frameToCenter.origin.x = 0
        }
        
        if frameToCenter.size.height < boundsSize.height {
            frameToCenter.origin.y = (boundsSize.height - frameToCenter.size.height) / 2
        } else {
            frameToCenter.origin.y = 0
        }
        
        imageZoomView.frame = frameToCenter
    }
    
    // gesture
    @objc func handleZoomingTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let location = sender.location(in: sender.view)
        self.zoom(point: location, animated: true)
    }
    
    func zoom(point: CGPoint, animated: Bool) {
        let currectScale = self.zoomScale
        let minScale = self.minimumZoomScale
        let maxScale = self.maximumZoomScale
        
        if minScale == maxScale && minScale > 1 {
            return
        }
        
        let toScale = maxScale
        let finalScale = (currectScale == minScale) ? toScale : minScale
        let zoomRect = self.zoomRect(scale: finalScale, center: point)
        self.zoom(to: zoomRect, animated: animated)
    }
    
    func zoomRect(scale: CGFloat, center: CGPoint) -> CGRect {
        var zoomRect = CGRect.zero
        let bounds = self.bounds
        
        zoomRect.size.width = bounds.size.width / scale
        zoomRect.size.height = bounds.size.height / scale
        
        zoomRect.origin.x = center.x - (zoomRect.size.width / 2)
        zoomRect.origin.y = center.y - (zoomRect.size.height / 2)
        return zoomRect
    }
    
    // MARK: - UIScrollViewDelegate
    
    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return self.imageZoomView
    }
    
    func scrollViewDidZoom(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        self.centerImage()
    }
    
}
```

but when loading complete it doesnt work, only empty screen
and in console I have strange logs

> 2022-09-19 16:58:35.169270+0300 Storage[11768:301086] [Assert] -[UIScrollView _clampedZoomScale:allowRubberbanding:]: Must be called with non-zero scale
> 2022-09-19 16:58:35.169587+0300 Storage[11768:301086] [Unknown process name] CGAffineTransformInvert: singular matrix.